# Add a header to a string and sending it with TCP socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcpclient

I have a client/server that exchanges messages,  and i am trying to add the size of the string i am sending, in the beginning of the string, in order for the server to know how many bytes to read. 
I added the message starting from the +4 pos of the char* and used memcpy to copy the strlen of the string. It doesnt seem to work and something tells me its the wrong way to do it. This is my code.

```
//*CLIENT*//
send_message = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(send_message + 4,"GETFILES ");
strcat(send_message,"/");
strcat(send_message,directory_name);
size = strlen(send_message) + 1;
csize = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
csize = (char*)&size;
memcpy(&send_message,csize,4);

if((sent = send(sock, send_message, strlen(send_message) + 1, 0)) < 0)
     perror("write");



//*SERVER*//
while(1){
    count = recv(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof(buf),0);
    if(count == -1){
     //if errno = EAGAIN we have read all data. going back to main loop
          if(errno != EAGAIN){
                perror("read");
                done = 1;
          }
          break;
    }
    else if(count == 0){
     //End of file. The remote has closed the connections
      done = 1;
       break;
    }
    printf("received message %s and count %d\n", buf, count);
 }
```

if i comment these lines

```
csize = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
csize = (char*)&size;
memcpy(send_message,csize,4);
```

I get this output:

```
 received message ▒�w�GETFILES /test and count 19
```

otherwise i get no output..Any ideas how to fix it and add the header so my server knows in advance how many bytes to read?

Comment: You can't use `strlen` when you call `send`.  The message starts with a 4 byte length which may contain bytes with the same value as a string terminator.

Comment: In addition to what @simonc said, consider the strcpy, strcat of your client... strcpy is ok since you're starting 4 bytes in (but hard coded 4 is not cool)... but you then strcat based on the beginning. The same problem simonc observes will be here, causing strcat to put things somewhere other than where you expect.

Comment: is it a better practise to use memcpy instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented already, the main problem is the use of strlen(), but there is some more error.

First the `strlen()` and other str functions could be used in this way.

```
strcpy(send_message + 4,"GETFILES ");
strcat(send_message + 4,"/");
strcat(send_message + 4,directory_name);
size = strlen(send_message + 4) + 1;
```

It is not a good way to fix it, but it is easier to understand why your code is not working.

This is unnecessary

```
csize = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
csize = (char*)&size;
memcpy(&send_message,csize,4);
```

You could simply do this

```
memcpy(send_message,&size,4);
```

BUT, for good practice and portability, replace all your magic `4` for `sizeof(int32_t)`.

`send_message` is an array, so you do not need to get it address (&send_message), it may work this way, but if it was a pointer instead of an array it would break your code.

And last, you are printing the entire buff, but you forgot that you have a 4 bytes header, and that is the main reason it do not print anything if you properly initialize the `csize`.

If you try to do this

```
printf("received message %s and count %d\n", buf+4, count);
```

It will probably works, but it do not mean it is correct.

Edit: I will not update my answer to not make it bigger and harder to you see your mistake, but consider @thuovila comments below and look for more informations about `htonl` `ntohl` and how to use them.

Comment: Also, you shouldnt send an int raw over the wire. Please use `int_to_send = htonl(local_int)`;. Include it from `<arpa/inet.h>` . Sending ascii text works OK, but multibyte binary data (numbers) does not.

Comment: For the sake of symmetry, I should probably also mention that you should use `local_int = ntohl(int_read_from_network);` on the receiving side. Forgot that in my first comment.